# passing the state parameters through the OAuth flow

Tags: oauth, dwolla

We have a multi-tenant application (AccountingSuite.com) and we want to have a Connect to Dwolla button in the application.

The button will open:

`https://www.dwolla.com/oauth/v2/authenticate?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope={scope}&state={instance_id}`

notice there is the state parameter at the end identifying an instance in our multi-tenant app. After a successful authentication the response URI needs to contain the `state` parameter, otherwise it's impossible for us to find out which instance sent a connect request. Currently the `state` parameter is stripped in the return.

This is a pretty standard OAuth flow (see, for example Stripe).

Please let me what I don't do right, or pass through the state parameter in the OAuth flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Dwolla doesn't support a `state` parameter, as an alternative, you can specify the `state` parameter as a querystring variable in the `return_uri`.

For example, if you used this return URI:

```
http://www.example.com/somepage?state=foobar
```

After granting permissions to your application on Dwolla, the user will be redirected to your application via:

```
http://www.example.com/somepage?state=foobar&code={OAuth Verification Code}
```